# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Yacc / C

Tags: c, yacc

I am having a problem which I have never encountered before. I know which piece of code that is crashing the program, I just do not know how to solve it. I have two linked lists that are being searched for a specific "key" in two functions. Now, although the functions work properly with Ifs, it wont work as intended since it is not a loop, they will only go through the linked list one time and the info they send out is incorrect. I tried using a while which seems to be correct, but eventually it crashes the program for some reason. And that's where I would love some help with :)

yacc file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern int yylineno;
int r; int c; int n;
typedef struct{char c[50]; int *p;} em;
%}
%union {struct {char c[50];} buf; struct esta{char info[50]; int nu; struct esta *next;} *p; struct trans{char esti[50]; char estf[50]; char nome[50]; int nu; struct trans *next;} *q;}
%start gda
%token<buf> BEGINTAG ENDTAG DEFINETAG AUT EST CODC
%type<p> desta naute aute nest dest 
%type<q> dtraa nautt autt ntra dtra
%type<buf> devea deve eve com
%%
gda  : gda desta dtraa devea {struct trans *t;struct esta *ei;struct esta *ef;t=getTransInfo($3,$4.c);ei=getEstInfo($2,t->esti);ef=getEstInfo($2,t->estf);printf("%s %s %s %d %s %d\n",t->esti,t->estf,ei->info,ei->nu,ef->info,ef->nu);}
     |
     ;
desta: DEFINETAG BEGINTAG naute ENDTAG {$$=$3;}
     ;
naute: naute aute {$$=$2;}
     | aute {$$=$1;}
     ;
aute : AUT nest {$$=$2;}
     ;
nest : nest dest {$$=$2;$2->next=$1;r++;$2->nu+=r;}
     | dest {$$=$1;$1->next=0;r=0;}
     ;
dest : EST {$$=newEst($1.c);}
     ;
dtraa: DEFINETAG BEGINTAG nautt ENDTAG {$$=$3;}
     ;
nautt: nautt autt {$$=$2;}
     | autt {$$=$1;}
     ;
autt : AUT ntra {$$=$2;}
     ;
ntra : ntra dtra {$$=$2;$2->next=$1;c++;$2->nu+=c;}
     | dtra {$$=$1;$1->next=0;c=0;}
     ;
dtra : EST '-''>' EST '(' EST ')' {$$=newTrans($1.c,$4.c,$6.c);}
     ;
devea: devea AUT BEGINTAG deve ENDTAG {$$=$4;}
     | AUT BEGINTAG deve ENDTAG {$$=$3;}
     ;
deve : deve eve CODC {$$=$2;}
     | eve CODC {$$=$1;}
     ;
eve  : '(' com ')'':' com {$$=$2;}
     ;
com  : EST {strcpy($$.c,$1.c);}
     ;
%%
int main(){
yyparse();
return 0;
}
int yyerror(char *s){fprintf(stderr, "ERRO(%d):%s\n", yylineno,s); return 0;}
struct esta *newEst(char c[50]){struct esta *p=(struct esta*) malloc(sizeof(struct esta)); strcpy(p->info,c); p->nu=1; p->next=0 ; return p;}
struct trans *newTrans(char ei[50],char ef[50],char n[50]){struct trans *q=(struct trans*)malloc(sizeof(struct trans));strcpy(q->esti,ei);strcpy(q->estf,ef);strcpy(q->nome,n);q->nu=1;q->next=0;return q;}
struct esta *getEstInfo(struct esta *s,char c[50]){if(s->info!=c){s=s->next;}else{return s;}}
struct trans *getTransInfo(struct trans *s,char c[50]){while(s->nome!=c){s=s->next;}return s;}
```

The functions that I was talking about were the last two. getEstInfo and getTransInfo. They both need to be changed to whiles I think, but I don't know how. Any other comments about how can I make my code more efficient are gladly accepted. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can't you tidy up this code a bit? This looks almost like an obfuscation contest entry. :)

Comment: And where does it crash?

Comment: It crashes when I use a while in last function(getTransInfo). This code works 100% right if I write both functions with Ifs(getEstInfo). But I have to use whiles, that is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Please removed [Solved] from the title, add your solution as an answer and then accept it. That's the preferred way to handle a Solution Selfie.

Comment: (but please format your code before posting that as an answer, it's seriously horrible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. After failing and failing over again, I re-implemented the last two functions, and I got it working with whiles:

```
struct esta *getEstInfo (struct esta *s, char c[50])
{
    int i;

    while (s)
    {
        i = strcmp(s->info, c);
        if (i != 0)
        {
            s=s->next;
        } else
        {
            return s;
            break;
        }
    }
}

struct trans *getTransInfo (struct trans *s,char c[50])
{
    int i;

    while (s)
    {
        i = strcmp (s->nome, c);
        if (i != 0)
        {
            s = s->next;
        } else
        {
            return s;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time anyway :)